# Magento 2: How can i use resource models for delete record instead of use delete method?

Tags: magento2

How can i use resource models for delete record instead of use delete method ?

Currently i used below code for delete item:

```
$post = $this->customCollection->load($itemId);
$post->delete();
```

but i need to use resource models for deleting data.

any idea please share.

Comment: check my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228593/get-database-connection-in-magento-2/228598#228598

You want like this?

Comment: No Nikunj, We need to use Resource model for delete data.

Comment: At the end the function is in resource model, please provide more details about it.

Comment: @kunj, in ResourceModel , there is one method _construct with code of $this->_init('modulename', 'id');

Comment: but you extended `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb` file in your custom resource. You will see `public function delete(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)`  method in that `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb` file.

Comment: @kunj can you share your idea for how can i use this AbstractDb for my custom module ?

Comment: basic Magento using this way check this file `vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block.php`